# métodos de configuração não funcionam em projeto Maven com Spring-boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

tenho as 3 classes que transcrevi o código. o método run no boot starta minha aplicação. as outras duas classes estão no pacote que contém as configurações. estou usando spring boot e tenho um arquivo pom com diversas dependências, startes básicos do boot, o tomcat, o maven, javax, validation, hibernate-validator, servlet e plugins. Não consegui que o login fosse configurado e funcionasse, o mesmo para o encoder que não foi aplicado quando tentei criar um usuário com senha.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Boot extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bundle = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    bundle.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages");
    bundle.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    bundle.setCacheSeconds(1);
    return bundle;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Boot.class);
    // tried this too
    // return application.sources(Boot.class, AppWebConfiguration.class, WebSecurityConfig.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Boot.class, args);
}

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home").permitAll().antMatchers("/home/**").permitAll()
            // .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/products/form").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/shopping/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/products").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/products/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
            .permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/WEB-INF/views/errors/403.jsp");
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
}

@EnableWebMvc
public class AppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
}
```

Comment: tenta usar: 
'@EnableAutoConfiguration' após '@SpringBootApplication'